# Android external storage folder ( created via SAF) and its contents wrongly removed by cleaner

Tags: android, storage, storage-access-framework, android-11

```
private void triggerStorageAccessFramework() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_ACCESS);
}
```

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_ACCESS) {

```
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            // Get Uri from Storage Access Framework.
            Uri treeUri = data.getData();

            // Persist access permissions.
            final int takeFlags = data.getFlags()
                    & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, takeFlags);


            DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(DocumentTreeActivity.this, treeUri);

           

            DocumentFile rootDir = pickedDir.findFile("Images");

            if (rootDir == null || !rootDir.exists()) {
                rootDir = pickedDir.createDirectory("Images");
             
            }
```

}
}

I can create the folder,i can read & write the files from/to the folder. Later, after running the cleaner (inbuilt, Redmi note 8 pro) app, the folder and files got deleted. I doubt the folder is detecting as residual . Anybody please help. Forgive my bad english

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
` Better remove those flags. They make no sense. You cannot grant anything.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing the name of the folder with a name other than application name. I don't know the logic/trick behind. But it works.